# DataDog how to disable Redis integration

Tags: kubernetes, redis, datadog

I've installed the DataDog agent on my Kubernetes cluster using the Helm chart (https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/datadog).

This works very well except for one thing. I have a number of Redis containers that have passwords set. This seems to be causing issues for the DataDog agent because it can't connect to Redis without a password.

I would like to either disable monitoring Redis completely or somehow bypass the Redis authentication. If I leave it as is I get a lot of error messages in the DataDog container logs and the redisdb integration shows up in yellow in the DataDog dashboard.

What are my options here?

Answer (score 0):

I am not a fan of helm, but you can accomplish this in 2 ways:

- via env vars: make use of `DD_AC_EXCLUDE` variable to exclude the Redis containers: eg `DD_AC_EXCLUDE=name:prefix-redis`
- via a config map: mount an empty config map in `/etc/datadog-agent/conf.d/redisdb.d/`, below is an example where I renamed the `auto_conf.yaml` to `auto_conf.yaml.example`.

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  auto_conf.yaml.example: |
    ad_identifiers:
      - redis    init_config:    instances:
        ## @param host - string - required
        ## Enter the host to connect to.
        #
      - host: "%%host%%"        ## @param port - integer - required
        ## Enter the port of the host to connect to.
        #
        port: "6379"
  conf.yaml.example: |
    init_config:    instances:        ## @param host - string - required
        ## Enter the host to connect to.
        # [removed content]
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  name: redisdb-d
```

alter the daemonset/deployment object:

```
[....]
        volumeMounts:
        - name: redisdb-d
          mountPath: /etc/datadog-agent/conf.d/redisdb.d
[...]
      volumes:
      - name: redisdb-d
        configMap:
          name: redisdb-d

[...]
```